# How can one obtain translations of foreign research papers?

Tags: publications, translations

Recently, I've found a Danish scholarly [article](http://www.tifp.dk/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Erhvervsdrivende-fondes-historie.pdf) on industrial foundations. As far as I know, the article is only available in Danish. Unfortunately, I'm not able to speak or read this language.

**Question**: is there any way I can obtain a proper English translation of this article? Are there perhaps any academic translation services, or translation collectives that might translate it *pro bono*?

Comment: For non technical work (equations and such - math) Google Translate does a pretty good job. A highly specialized vocabulary gets in the way, however. My experience with Danish academics (CS people) is that they all speak English at a high level, so you could just ask them for help.

Comment: @Buffy Yeah Google Translate works okay, I was just hoping there might be more specialized services out there. Contacting the author is probably a good idea.

Comment: From Amsterdam you could just go there, perhaps. ;-) Seven and a half hour drive to Aarhus. Or meet up at a tavern in Hamburg.

Comment: You could try to contact the authors

Comment: @Buffy - I’m guessing there is likely a Dane down the hall he could treat to a nice rijsttafel in exchange for a translation...